# Puppeteer not Works when published to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, docker, puppeteer

I have a node js API with puppeteer to print HTML. everything works correctly in the localhost but, when I publish to azure app service it's not working. I think the problem is browser.exe is not working in azure app service is there any way to make it work any other workaround to make it work.

This is my code

```
exports.print = (req, res, next) => {
  (async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
   const page = await browser.newPage()
   await page.goto('./printTest.html', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
   const buffer = await page.pdf({format: 'A4'})
   res.type('application/pdf')
   res.send(buffer)
   browser.close()
})()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `{args: ['--no-sandbox']}` to `await puppeteer.launch()`

```
await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']})
```

Comment: this did not work for me